# Unknow parameter returnUrl identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, uri

I am facing a problem using identity to authenticate the user in a project I am working on.
I have no idea why, but after leaving `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` a parameter returnUrl is added to my uri and makes it crash because the uri is too long.

Here is the uri returned

```
http://localhost:51092/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2FLogin%2FIndex%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FLogin%252FIndex%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FLogin%25252FIndex%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FLogin%2525252FIndex%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FLogin%252525252FIndex%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FLogin%25252525252FIndex%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525252FIndex%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252FIndex%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252FIndex%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252FIndex%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252FIndex%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252FIndex%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252FIndex%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252FIndex%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252FIndex%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252FIndex%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252FIndex%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252FIndex%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FIndex%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIndex
```

Plus the list of errors is displayed and the physical path of my controller is weird because Index is the function that should be called but it seems it's like a file

```
C:\Projects\vs\project\project\Login\Index
```

here is my cConfiguration function

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                }
            });
```

If someone is seeing something wrong

Edit: Here is my function Index in Login controller

```
    // GET: Login
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

```
using Gesmar_intra.Models;
using Gesmar_intra.Models.Entite;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Gesmar_intra.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        protected Gesmar db = new Gesmar();

        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

        public LoginController()
        {
        }

        public LoginController(ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }


        // GET: Login
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
            var username = Request.Form["username"];
            var password = Request.Form["password"];
            var passHash = Utilisateur.GenerateSHA256String(password);
            if (Utilisateur.CheckAccount(username, "APRRR", password))
            {
                password = "";
            }
            var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(username, password, false, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Test", "Login");
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View();
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return View();
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentative de connexion non valide.");
                    return View();
            }
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is handling the `/Login/Index` request? Do you have an action method for that? Can you show us?

Comment: I added the method of my controller

Comment: Try opening dev tools and watching the network tab. It looks like you're being infinitely redirected and it's trying to auto add the return url to every request. The `Login/Index` method is accessible anonymously, right?

Comment: Do you have `Authorize` attribute on the `Login` controller?

Comment: Nope Login controller hasn't authorize tag anyone can access it, and yeah it seems it's always redirecting maybe it's because i didn't put a parameter in the Index() ?

Comment: Can you add the error messages to your question? The answer usually lies in the error messages :)

Comment: Yep, I added the full error page, could it be something wrong with my web.config ?

Comment: Can you show the entire controller that contains the Login/Index action pls.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules?

Comment: Everything is the default configuration, and first I did it in an separate project where everything is working perfectly, and when I am adding this to the actual project it's not working anymoer :s